# Teradata backup and restore

Tags: backup, teradata, restore

We want to take a BACKUP of our data in Teradata and

- RESTORE it on another Teradata box. Is this possible, and if yes do we neeed to have same version of database on other teradata box? What are the tools available for this?
- RESTORE it on Teradata Emulator perhaps running on Windows/Linux box. Is this possible, if not entirely at least few tables?
- RESTORE it on Oracle Database, possible?
- RESTORE it on Hadoop/Hive system, possible?

Comment: A Backup taken by Teradata can only be restored to a Teradata system (version might be different, usually the source has a lower version than target). There's two tools: old Arcmain and newer DSA, simply read the manuals.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. I understand that there is something called Teradata emulator which perhaps can run on any host (not sure though). Is it possible to RESTORE data on such an emulator if it exists (may not be all but to few tables)?

Comment: I've never heard of something like *Teradata emulator*. Moving data from one DBMS to another is done using export & import.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2017/11/20/teradata-backup-to-azure-blob-storage-using-data-stream-controller-dsc/ talks about setting up Teradata on VM and doing backup/restore. We want to do something similar i.e. take backup of REAL teradata appliance (please note: we use Netvault to take "Tape backup" of this system) and restore it on a VM (running Teradata system). Is it possible ?

Comment: Of course you can restore (actually it's a COPY) to another Teradata system using Netvault

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant:

1. Yes, you can. Make sure that system you're restoring backup to is the same version or higher. Most basic tool you can use - "arc" also known as arcmain. It is part of Teradata Tools and Utilities pack. But make sure you're using for restore very same version of ARC as you were using for backup.  More advansed tools are: DSU from Teradata (or ABU in older versions), NetBackup from Symantec.
2. If by Emulator you mean Teradata VM - yes, again possible with same conditions mentioned in #1.
3. Not by backup-restore. It would be more export-import operation rather than backup-restore. And you need to use custom tools for it.
4. Same as #3. There is a tool called Teradata Connector for Hadoop that can help you with data movement between Teradata and Hadoop.